# FusionAuth OpenID connect with Azure AD has integration issue

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, fusionauth

I am using the FusionAuth and I want to add Azure AD as OpenID connect Identity provider. 
I have added it and check. I enter email, then I redirected to Microsoft login page where I do log in with my credentials and I get the error on screen, which is saying is, Internal server error.

So I check the log and get the error log stack trace. So here I am providing the stack trace here.

Help me with this!

> Jan 17, 2020 3:48:56.554 PM ERROR
>   io.fusionauth.app.primeframework.error.ExceptionExceptionHandler - An
>   unhandled exception was thrown
>   org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.el.MissingPropertyExpressionException:
>   While evaluating the expression
>   [client_id=9ecc54b7-6f79-4105-a208-ca61e6157b58&identityProviderId=2a431005-6f6d-400c-8d57-ac320115c9a5&metaData.device.name=Windows+Chrome&metaData.device.type=BROWSER&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fipos%2Frest%2FfusionAuth%2FcallBack&response_type=code&scope=offline_access&state=_1011212111025&tenantId=33666534-3166-3865-3838-616265663235&timezone=Asia%2FCalcutta].
>   The property/field
>   [client_id=9ecc54b7-6f79-4105-a208-ca61e6157b58&identityProviderId=2a431005-6f6d-400c-8d57-ac320115c9a5&metaData]
>   does not exist in the class [class
>   io.fusionauth.app.action.oauth2.CallbackAction]
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.el.MemberAccessor.(MemberAccessor.java:84)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.el.Expression.next(Expression.java:147)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.el.Expression.traverseToEndForSet(Expression.java:113)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.el.DefaultExpressionEvaluator.setValue(DefaultExpressionEvaluator.java:131)
>           at io.fusionauth.app.action.oauth2.BaseOAuthAction.decodeAndRestoreState(BaseOAuthAction.java:365)
>           at io.fusionauth.app.action.oauth2.CallbackAction.get(CallbackAction.java:92)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.util.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:414)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.execute(DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.java:79)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.perform(DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.java:62)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.validation.DefaultValidationWorkflow.perform(DefaultValidationWorkflow.java:47)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.security.DefaultSecurityWorkflow.perform(DefaultSecurityWorkflow.java:60)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultPostParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultPostParameterWorkflow.java:50)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.content.DefaultContentWorkflow.perform(DefaultContentWorkflow.java:52)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultParameterWorkflow.java:57)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultURIParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultURIParameterWorkflow.java:102)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.scope.DefaultScopeRetrievalWorkflow.perform(DefaultScopeRetrievalWorkflow.java:58)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.message.DefaultMessageWorkflow.perform(DefaultMessageWorkflow.java:45)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
>           at io.fusionauth.app.primeframework.FrontEndTenantWorkflow.perform(FrontEndTenantWorkflow.java:163)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionMappingWorkflow.perform(DefaultActionMappingWorkflow.java:126)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.StaticResourceWorkflow.perform(StaticResourceWorkflow.java:97)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.RequestBodyWorkflow.perform(RequestBodyWorkflow.java:89)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.security.DefaultSavedRequestWorkflow.perform(DefaultSavedRequestWorkflow.java:57)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
>           at io.fusionauth.app.primeframework.CORSFilter.handleNonCORS(CORSFilter.java:291)
>           at io.fusionauth.app.primeframework.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:252)
>           at io.fusionauth.app.primeframework.CORSRequestWorkflow.perform(CORSRequestWorkflow.java:48)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43)
>           at io.fusionauth.app.primeframework.FusionAuthMVCWorkflow.perform(FusionAuthMVCWorkflow.java:88)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.DefaultWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(DefaultWorkflowChain.java:44)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.servlet.FilterWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(FilterWorkflowChain.java:50)
>           at org.primeframework.mvc.servlet.PrimeFilter.doFilter(PrimeFilter.java:84)
>           at com.inversoft.maintenance.servlet.MaintenanceModePrimeFilter.doFilter(MaintenanceModePrimeFilter.java:59)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at com.inversoft.servlet.UTF8Filter.doFilter(UTF8Filter.java:27)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Can you enable debug for this IdP configuration to see if there is anything interesting in the Debug or Event Event Log (System > Event Log)? The one thing of note is the exception `client_id=9ecc54b7-6f79-4105-a208-ca61e6157b58&identityProviderId=2a431005-6f6d-400c-8d57-ac320115c9a5&metaData`, this seems to indicate the request to Azure or on the way back is not encoded properly.

Comment: @robotdan Thanks for the reply. I will enable debug for this IDP and also will enable the Event Log and will update here. It happens when the request is on the way back from Azure.

Comment: It seems like there is an issue with how the `state` parameter is being passed back to FusionAuth or how the state parameter is being encoded on the way to Azure.

Comment: @robotdan I have enabled debug in the IDP, but still, I get the same error stack trace and no other information in the log. Second, I check the Event Log also, It has also no new entry for this error. So please help me with this.

Comment: I need a lot more information, please open a GitHub issue with as much information as you can provide. Ideally the full request to Azure and the response.